# Push notification Doesnt work when the Application is running(Active)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Im working on a simple application with push notification and I successfully implemented it. When I exit the application, Im getting a push notification(Works well) but when I open the app and try to send a message from my server(Web application), It doesn't display any popup message or notification on it. Did I missed something? Here is my code snippet on AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {

// Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
 return YES;
 }


 (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary*)userInfo{
  NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
  NSString *messageAlert = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
  NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", messageAlert );
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:messageAlert];

 }
```

Please help me regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: It does not display notifications, but do you see the logs: "Received notification: XXX" and "Received Push Badge: YYY" (where XXX and YYY are strings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you app is Active Mode you need to put this method something like bellow into your Appdelegate class:-

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {    
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
        NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
        NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My App Name"
                                                            message:message 
                                                           delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];


    } else {
        //Do stuff that you would do if the application was not active
    }
}
```

Also put `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` delegate for checking Fail Reason

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", error];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect of this code: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:messageAlert];`??

I guess you miss some basics.. to present an Alert, you should have a look at `UIAlertView`. The `NSNotificationCenter` is for internal data flow in your application. (Observer Pattern)

While your app is running, no alert will be presented automatically. You need to handle the push message on your own starting in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. The `NSNotificationCenter` and `Push Notifications` are totally different things. They are not part of each other.

Answer (score 0):

If I recalled correctly, Apple deliver push notifications to different places when your app is running or not. You have implemented only non-launched code but not during-execution part.